# Reverse for 'project_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/projects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-urls, web-development-server, django-url-reverse

I am trying to figure out why it is that I am getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/projects/delete/1/
Reverse for 'project_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/projects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Here's the url for the catalog app. I think the problem is from here but I don't seem to be able to figure it out

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', views.ProjectListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('projects/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
    path('projects/new/', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project_new'),
    path('projects/edit/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project_edit'),
    path('projects/delete/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project_delete')
]
```

**views.py**

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
        'projects': Project.objects.all(),
        'num_projects': Project.objects.all().count(),
        'num_ongoing_projects': Project.objects.filter(status__exact='OG').count(),
        'num_clients': Client.objects.count(),
    }
        return context


class ProjectListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    model = Project
    paginate_by = 10


class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    context_object_name = 'project_detail'
    template_name = 'catalog/project_detail.html'


class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    # login_url = '/login/'
    form_class = ProjectForm
    model = Project
    redirect_field_name = 'catalog/project_detail.html'


class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields=('project_title', 'location', 'status', 'start_date', 'end_date')
    # form_class = ProjectForm
    model = Project
    redirect_field_name = 'catalog/project_detail.html'


class ProjectDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Project
    success_url = reverse_lazy('catalog:list')
```

The edit button works fine but the delete button doesn't. It produces that error code

**project_detail.html**

```
{% extends "catalog/catalog_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Welcome to Project Detail Page</h1>
<h2>Project details:</h2>
<p><strong>Project Number:</strong> {{project_detail.project_number}}</p>
<p><strong>Project Title:</strong> {{project_detail.project_title}}</p>
<p><strong>Customer:</strong> {{project_detail.client}}</p>
<p><strong>Further For:</strong> {{project_detail.further_for}}</p>
<p><strong>Location:</strong> {{project_detail.location}}</p>
<p><strong>Status:</strong> {{project_detail.status}}</p>
<p><strong>Start Date:</strong> {{project_detail.start_date}}</p>
<p><strong>End Date:</strong> {{project_detail.end_date}}</p> <br>
<p><strong>Summary:</strong> {{project_detail.summary}}</p>
<hr>


<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'catalog:project_edit' pk=project_detail.pk %}">
    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
  </a>

  <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'catalog:project_delete' pk=project_detail.pk  %}">
    <span class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**project_form.html**

```
{% extends "catalog/catalog_base.html" %}


{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <h1>Create New Project</h1>
  <h3><em>Enter project details:</em></h3><br>
  <form id="create" method="POST">
    {{ form|crispy }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Project">
  </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

**project_confirm_delete.html**

```
{% extends "catalog/catalog_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Delete {{project.project_number}}?</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
    <a href="{% url 'catalog:project_detail' pk=project_detail.pk %}">Cancel</a>

  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: replace pk=project_detail.pk to pk=project.pk where every you calling may be contect vriable name worng

Comment: ```context_object_name = 'project_detail'```

Comment: or just use href="{% url 'catalog:project_detail' project_detail.pk %}" and pk= not required